No overload for 'Search1' matches delegate 'Func<string, CancellationToken, Task<IEnumerable<string>>>'
I am learning  about MudAutocomplete code from   https://mudblazor.com/components/autocomplete#api  and copy code to run test but I found error   'No overload for 'Search1'  matches delegate 'Func<string, CancellationToken, Task<IEnumerable<string>>>''
<MudGrid>

    <MudItem xs="12" sm="6" md="4">
        <MudAutocomplete T="string" Label="US States" @bind-Value="value1" SearchFunc="@Search1"  Variant="Variant.Outlined" />
    </MudItem>
</MudGrid>

@code {

    private string value1;
    private string[] states =
    {
        "Alabama", "Alaska", "American Samoa", "Arizona",
        "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut",
        "Delaware", "District of Columbia", "Federated States of Micronesia",
        "Florida", "Georgia", "Guam", "Hawaii", "Idaho",
        "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky",
        "Louisiana", "Maine", "Marshall Islands", "Maryland",
        "Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Mississippi",
    };

    private async Task<IEnumerable<string>> Search1(string value)
    {
        // In real life use an asynchronous function for fetching data from an api.
        await Task.Delay(5);

        // if text is null or empty, show complete list
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            return states;
        return states.Where(x => x.Contains(value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
    }
}

How can I find  solution ?  Thank you.

Is the code you posted the same as the one you're using, or is it taken from the documentation? If it is not the code you're using, can you check if you maybe used SearchFuncWithCancel instead of SearchFunc?
It works fine on trymudblazor https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/cEcyYqOLIpvMhyYa
. I checked my project. I'm using the latest version of mudblazor and it compiles fine.

just add a cancellation token parameter to your method Search1(string value, CancellationToken token)

MudBlazor Autocomplete component has two properties, SearchFunc and SearchFuncWithCancel.
If you want to use cancelation token, use the second one SearchFuncWithCancel and in that case, you may want to create a method:
private async Task<IEnumerable<string>> Search1(string value, CancellationToken token) { ---All the stuff in method}

Otherwise, if you are using just SearchFunc, then just delete CancellationToken from method parameters and you should be fine.
private async Task<IEnumerable<string>> Search1(string value){}

